# Google Drive SDK: MediaUploadProgress - not sure how to use this

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am looking to provide upload progress to my CLI using MediaIOUploadBase, and I can see there is a class called MediaUploadProgress, but it isn't a wrapper to an upload so I'm presuming it is obtained from an active upload somehow.  I can't find any documentation in the apiclient.http library on how to obtain upload progress.  Does anybody know how this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the latest status similar to what I'm attaching below.

```
media = MediaFileUpload('image.png', mimetype='image/png', chunksize=1000, resumable=True)
request = drive.files().update(id='fileId', media_body=media)

response = None
while response is None:
  status, response = request.next_chunk()
  if status:
    print status.progress()
```

Comment: Funnily enough, I did eventually find an example just like this, hidden away in the depths of the apiclient source code.  Thanks!